# Unable to authenticate OAuth2 with Akka-Http

Tags: scala, oauth-2.0, geometry, akka-http

Hi have a service developed using Akka-Http. I have to add OAuth to it and according to the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/security-directives/authenticateOAuth2.html), I am using `authenticateOAuth2` for this.

However the code isn't compiling and gives the error as

> Type mismatch, expected: (L) => server.Route, actual: (OauthInfo) => server.Route

I am unable to find a proper solution to fix this issue. I even tried the exact code mentioned in the [example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/security-directives/authorize.html) in the documentation but it still throws similar compile time error.

I am using akka-http with circle.

Here is my code:

```
def route(implicit system: ActorSystem, mat: ActorMaterializer): Route =
Route.seal {
  pathPrefix("newsletter-preferences") {
    authenticateOAuth2(realm = "Secure site", authenticator) { authInfo =>
      path("frequency" / LongNumber) { custNum =>
        authorize(hasScopes(authInfo)) {
          frequencyPreference(custNum) ~ addFreqPref(custNum)
        }
      } ~ path("pause" / LongNumber) { custNum =>
        authorize(hasScopes(authInfo)) {
          pauseInfo(custNum) ~ addPauseInfo(custNum) ~ unPauseUser(custNum)
        }
      }
    } ~
      path("health") {
        healthRoute()
      }
  }
}

def hasScopes(authInfo: OAuthInfo): Boolean = ???

def authenticator(credentials: Credentials)(
  implicit system: ActorSystem,
  mat: ActorMaterializer): Option[OAuthInfo] = {
credentials match {
  case p @ Credentials.Provided(token) =>
    ???
  case _ => None
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an error in IntelliJ.
The code runs fine but due to some reason IntelliJ Idea shows error all over it.